# Database file reserved space

Tags: sql-server, datafile, auto-growth

What are the possible reasons that a SQL Server database file reserved space is 95 percent of the total space? My database file has increased drastically and it shows that the actual space used is 5 percent while 95 percent is reserved.

Comment: Are you running any versioning related features? (RCSI, readable secondaries)

Answer (score 3):

The usual reason for a data file to contain a lot of empty space is a large amount of data being removed. The space is kept as reserved rather than returned to the filesystem in case it is needed again, until you do something like a `DBCC SHRINKFILE`. Perhaps a lot of short-lived data was added to, and removed from, the tables in that file recently?

Instead or as well as that, it could be that indexes have been dropped entirely, similarly freeing up space that is kept as reserved rather than being returned to the filesystem. Also rebuilding an index may consume a lot of space temporarily, and again once freed this is not automatically returned to file filesystem.

Comment: Could changing autogrow to unlimited cause extra free (reserved ) space in the database?

Comment: @FatimaHaroon – not really. It will grow by the same amount for the same activity, the difference limiting autogrow will make is that it will error-out once the set limit(s) are reached.

Comment: Thakyou so much for the help! I will investigate further according to what you have mentioned.

Comment: Just a quick last question: can updating the system cause change in the indexes? I am quite new and learning, so maybe a stupid question.

Comment: @FatimaHaroon - that depends on what you mean by "update the system". Updating SQL Server or the base OS should not cause significant growth. Some application updates may restructure the indexes along with other schema changes, or might just rebuild the existing indexes - this can cause some growth and leave reserved space after but I wouldn't expect to see nearly that much reserved space because of this unless a lot of indexes were dropped entirely.